# Iframe crashing while debugger is ON on chrome or anything if i write in console

Tags: debugging, console, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on a iframe. When i try to put a debugger, generally my page crashes.Please see the image [Crashed Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iUt9.png) . 
Please note that - my chrome is updated and I have uninstalled and installed multiple times.

Appreciate if anyone would provide any pointers !

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome. You can report it on https://crbug.com.

Answer (score 0):

chrome has been updated recently. Might be issue from their side. Try different browser. And raise issue to chrome